# appcfg.sh update_dispatch stopped working

Tags: google-app-engine

I had been using the dispatch feature to route certain requests to a backend module that does Push Notifications. It was working fine until recently, now my requests are not being routed and thus the feature no longer working.

Here is my dispatch.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <dispatch-entries>
  <dispatch>
      <!-- Send all admin/push traffic to the push notifications backend module. -->
      <url>*admin/push*</url>
      <module>push-notifications</module>
  </dispatch>
</dispatch-entries>
```

And after running appcfg.sh update_dispatch  I get a "Success" message.

The admin console shows the dispatch information:
[image]

However, the requests are not being routed at all. I have tried updating to the latest SDK, re-deploying my app, running the update_dispatch command multiple times.

The only thing I that I changed recently was that I am using a custom domain with an SSL Certificate, the last time the push notifications where working was a couple of days before I did this, could the custom domain stuff have anything to do with this issue?

I also did the same custom domain stuff on another app (which is used as another environment) but has the same code base deployed to it and I noticed the same problem occurs there, the dispatch stopped working. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The API calls being made to *admin/push* originated from a Push Task Queue, I originally didn't know that I could target a specific module using the queue.xml file and thus I was relying on the dispatch to route the requests to the module. I just started using the "target" field in the queue.xml file to directly target the push notifications module (by-passing the need for the dispatch) and the module is now receiving the API calls as expected.

It goes without saying that there is still something funky happening with the dispatch functionality after I started using the custom domain, I just hope I don't have to use it for something else.

Comment: We hit the same issue... the only way we could route the /_ah/queue things was adding the <target> entry in the queue.xml.  Modifying the dispatch.xml made no difference at all.